# Defining functions in Python

Tags: python

I have a Python code like this,

```
def cube(n):
    n = n * n * n
    return n

    def by_three(n):
        if (n % 3 == 0):
         print "number is divisible by three"
         cube(n)
         return n
        else:
            print "number is not  divisible by three"
            return False
```

Currently I am not able to return any value, please let me know what is the issue?

Comment: please revisit the indentation, it seems wrong. (don't define functions inside functions except you know what you are doing). Also: How do you call the functions?

Comment: In `cube()`, you can simply say `def cube(n): return n ** 3`

Comment: After fixing the indentation, this code works.  Is there a question, or should this be posted to codereview?

Comment: @helloV please do not change the indentation of code unless the OP specifies that it should be changed. In your edit, you changed the entire scope of the question.

Comment: Oops. sorry @MattDMo. Now I notice my mistake. It was done in a haste.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not set the value of `cube(n)` in your `by_three` function to return.

```
def cube(n):
    result = n ** 3 # You can use ** for powers.
    return result

def by_three(n):
    if (n % 3 == 0):
        print "number is divisible by three"
        result = cube(n)
        return result
    else:
        print "number is not  divisible by three"
        return False
```

I am also assuming that you have made a mistake in your indentation when copying to SO. If that is not the case, and that is your original indentation, then you will need to rectify that also.

Comment: Or just `return n ** 3`.

Comment: Thanks @Ffisegydd this solved my problem also I understood the function definition and calling

Comment: or you could just say `return n ** 3` or `return cube(n)` (save memory space)